# Convert char array to a vector with 4-bit elements

Tags: c++, vector, bitset

I want to use the following code segment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm> 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    static const char szBits[] = "110101011010";   
    std::vector<std::bitset<4> > str(szBits, szBits + sizeof szBits);   
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::bitset<4> > (std::cout, "\n")); 

    return 0;
}
```

to get a vector with its 3 elements looks like
1101
1010
1010

But I can't obtain the correct result of what I expected.

Could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: What result are you seeing in place of what you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::bitset<4> > str(szBits, szBits + sizeof szBits);
```

That is obviously wrong. It actually creates the vector's item from each `char`, instead of `4 char` together.

This is what you should be doing:

```
static const char szBits[] = "110101011010";   
std::vector<std::bitset<4> > str;
for(size_t i = 0 ; (i + 4) < sizeof(szBits) ; i += 4 )
      str.push_back(std::bitset<4>(std::string(&szBits[i], 4))); 

std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::bitset<4> > (std::cout, "\n"));
```

Output:

```
1101
0101
1010
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/27RNL

Comment: @Golden Lee: If that helped you, then accept the answer by click on the `tick` mark. Additionally, you can also give upvote for being it helpful and correct.

Comment: Sorry Sir: I'm a newbie to stackoverflow. So, I'm not very familiar with its "operation" such as click tick, and give a vote.